# jQuery get post data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to get POST values in jQuery?

Comment: POST values are sent to the server, JQuery runs on the client. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yep, from a form. A pair of textboxs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

jQuery is for client-side Javascript. You grab POST values with server-side languages. You can provide them by mixing server-side with client-side:

```
<script>
(function() {
 var x = "<?php echo ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) && $_POST['name'] != '') ? $_POST['name'] : '';?>";
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Would this really work? Would it not be a massive security risk to be able to execute server side PHP from JavaScript, which is client side.

Comment: No, the server-side PHP is not exposed to the client. The commands within the <? and ?> are executed on the server, and the results of those are written to the client.

What the client sees is var x="John" (assuming "John" is the value of POST['name']

Answer (score 8):

```
$("form").serializeArray();
```

refer http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: This answer is out of the scope as it about sending post data and not receiving post data

Answer (score 2):

No, you could use whatever your back-end is to write some hidden fields on the page or write out a javascript script tag with the data, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you use AJAX methods to post you can send back the values or capture them prior to posting via the AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Use serializeArray on your form element http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/.

Answer (score 0):

To listen for POST values from another page?  Not as far as I know.  You can however submit a POST request via ajax to a server-side script and have the server side script return the previously POST-ed values (if you store them in the user's session, for example).

Comment: Is it possible to access the session, using jQuery, on the page data is sent to?

Comment: @NigelNquande - only by using the technique outlined in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3257289/135978) or by having your JavaScript make *another* request back to the server asking for the current state of the data.

Comment: Hmm. I think I'll have to post a question detailing what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

POST data is sent in the body of the request, usualy in a application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.

The last line here is what you want:

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: office@otb.expert
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 36

email=office@otb.expert&user+name=we
```

You can access the request body from PHP as $_POST. If the body is not in the format that you are expected you can try:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); $_POST = json_decode($postdata);
```

From server side you inject the content you need in your javascript:

```
<script>
  var x = "<?php echo ( isset( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? $_POST['email'] : 'we@otb.expert';?>";
</script>
```

If you still need to transport data from one page to another .html page and avoid .php files, you need to save your data before redirecting to the next page and than you can recover your data by reading the same storage.

So, use your database to keep the application state while navigating among pages.